I cannot get bootstrap Select and Input fields to be the same size form-control
I've tried a few different things to size the select field, including writing my own class. But it seems the only way is to copy the px generated for the input fields. However I'm afraid that by doing that it won't adaptively render on different devices/browsers.
I've even tried to write this css and leave it blank, but it generates another CSS class. If i do disable it in the inspect element, it renders the correct size.
'''
    select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
    height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);
}

'''
Any advice would be appreciated.


<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title></title>
</head>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<style> 
   .was-validated .form-control:invalid {
   border-color: #000000;
</style>
<style>
   .was-validated .form-control:valid {
   border-color: #000000; 
   };
</style>
<style>
   .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #008752 !important;
   font-family: 'Montserrat' !important;
   };
</style>
<style>
   .checkbox {
   color: #008752 !important;
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   }
</style>
<style>
   .p1 {
   color: #008752 !important;
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   };
</style>
<style>
   .h4{
   color: #008752 !important;
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   }
</style>
</style>
<form class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 was-validated" id="form" action="submit.php" method="post" style="font-family:Lucida Grande" >
<div class = "form-group container-fluid">
   <h4 class ="h4" >Registrant Name</h4>
   <label for="Registrant" class="inlineEditor" >Registrant Name </label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <input type="text" required name="FirstName" id=FirstName class="form-control"  placeholder="Your First Name" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);" />
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <input type="text" required name="LastName" id=LastName class="form-control" placeholder="Your Last Name" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class = "form-group container-fluid">
   <label for="Registrant" class="inlineEditor">Email</label>
   <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" >
         <input type="email" required class="form-control checking_email" name="Email" id="Email"  placeholder= "ex@example.com"oninput="checkemail()" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);"/>
         <small id="FirstName" class="text-muted">
         </small>
         <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please provide a valid email address.
         </div>
         <span id="check-email"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class = "form-group container-fluid">
   <label for="Address" class="inlineEditor" >Address</label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <input class="form-control "  required name="auto-address" id="auto-address" type="text" placeholder="123 Green Avenue" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);" />
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <input type="text"  name="Suite" id=Suite class="form-control" placeholder="Suite Number E.g. #1234" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group container-fluid">
   <label for="Registrant" class="inlineEditor">Personal Information</label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col ">
         <input id="DOB" required class="form-control" name="DOB" type="date"  max="2006-01-01" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);"/>
         <small id="FirstName" class="text-muted">
         Date of Birth. Must be over 18 to join.
         </small>
         <span id="startDateSelected"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col ">
         <input type="text" required id= Phone class="form-control" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number"  pattern="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{10}" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);">
      </div>
      <div class=" col">
         <select name ="work" id="work" required class="form-control" name = "work" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);">
            <option value="" disabled selected >Which Sector</option>
         </select >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <select name="secondwork" id="secondwork" class="form-control" required="yes" message="Please select body."  style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);">
            <option value="" disabled selected >Which  Organization</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <input type="text" name="input-box" class="form-control"  id="inputBox" hidden >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group container-fluid">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <label for="HearAbout"> Marketing</label>
      <Select id=HearAbout required class="form-control" name="HearAbout" placeholder="How did you hear about us" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);">
         <option value="" disabled selected>How Did you Hear About Us</option>
         <option> Letter</option>
         <option> Package</option>
      </Select>
   </div>
</div>




Sorry but., what exactly are you looking after? What are you referring to about "size the select box"?

select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) { height: calc(2.25rem + 2px); } gets applied to the field. As soon as I overwrite that with height: auto, it looks fine.

Did you try to update to bootstrap@4.6.2?

That was it! just needed to updated. TY!
